# How to select between two point range in google map

Tags: java, android

How to select  between two point range in google map. EX: 50m or 100m

i'm use this code to calculate distance.

```
    public class DistanceCalculator {

       public static final double Radius = 6378.1;

       public double CalculationByDistance(GeoPoint startp, GeoPoint endp) {
          double lat1 = startp.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
          double lat2 = endp.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
          double lon1 = startp.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
          double lon2 = endp.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
          double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
          double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
          double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
          Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
          double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
          return Radius * c;

       }
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to do, can you please be specific?

Answer (score 0):

MapViewController has a method called zoomToSpan(int, int).  So all you need to do it find the center of the two points and then zoom to the span between them.  Here is the documentation:

```
public void zoomToSpan(int latSpanE6,int lonSpanE6)
```

> Attempts to adjust the zoom of the map so that the given span of latitude and longitude will be
>   displayed. Because the zoom can only achieve discrete levels, and
>   because the aspect ratio of the map may not match the ratio given, the
>   quality of the fit may vary. The only thing we guarantee is that,
>   after the zoom, at least one of the new latitude or the new longitude
>   will be within a factor of 2 from the corresponding parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You try by calculating using the latittudes and longitudes by converting the degrees to distance (for instance from 1 degree lattitude to nautical mile).